# gradle sync fail in opening project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am a beginner still studying and i have this errors when i start the project new one any help pleas

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12. Open File Show Details

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
```

**and this this the message**

Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app

> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
>   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/216.58.208.110] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Connection timed out: connect

Comment: please, post app level gradle file. What´s your android studio version? which machine are you working in?

Comment: Have you tried synching your gradle

Comment: Have you tried synching your gradle

Comment: Levi Albuquerque its last version of android studio and i cant understand what you men about app level gradle file?

Comment: Its 4.1 version and android is 3.1

Comment: I tried to download new version of gradle 4.5.1 and make it manually but its give me the same error